# s3 cloudfront app Code: NoSuchKey on refreshing

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have my angular2 webapp hosted in s3. it has cloudfront as well. 
Its connecting to nodejs as backend which is in different machine in AWS EBS.

My web application works fine.But when i refresh any page , its throwing 404 Not Found with the below message.

```
Code: NoSuchKey
Message: The specified key does not exist.
Key: user/adduser/edit
RequestId: CA306FFABB30FB75
HostId: WAp7/BZMHH0UpE3z2dJLJT4gqEwv7u/LKbFTUuHH86lRyReLXvODLgTuTw+3emnTJ3jDj2VpiYo=
```

Can you help to resolve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I am not sure if its the correct thing to do.But it fixed my issue.
I configured s3 404 redirection url to be my index.html.ie pointed my 404 redirection to index.html itself. It worked.

Comment: We configure Cloudfront error handler for both 403 and 404 to return index.html with a 200 OK status.  In testing, it doesn't matter if the return is 200 or 404, the Angular2 app handles it the same.  It just looks nicer in Inspector to not be red for 404.

Comment: To support Janier's answer, you can reference this image https://i.imgur.com/VjzE2oA.png

Answer (score 2):

I was having this error that looks very similar to yours:
`error 404: no such key` on refreshing S3 website webpage.

Try adding "index.html" in the S3 bucket configurations:

1. Edit **static website hosting**
2. Set "Error document - optional"
3. and **type** "index.html"

This solution fixed my problem and I am confident that it will also fix yours.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error but using GCP (Google Cloud Platform) storage buckets instead of Amazon S3.  As @janier mentions configuring my app's main index page and error page settings to `index.html` resolved the issue.

In GCP go to your storage bucket in question and use the right side menu to access the **Website Configuration** as seen below:

[image: GCP Bucket Configuration]

In the following modal set your index and error pages to `index.html`

[image]

Then simply refresh your app and it should fixed!