# Can not access index.html from S3 bucket when it's in a folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket called `mywebsite.com`(not real name). In the bucket, I have the static contents of a website, in a folder called `build`.

The contents of the `build` folder `ls build/`:

```
asset-manifest.json     index.html              manifest.json           static
favicon.ico             lu1.png                 service-worker.js
```

I made the bucket public:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mywebsite.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

So I should be able to access the bucket from here:

http://mywebsite.com.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com (not real url)

Then, for the `Index document` and `Error document` I tried specifying this:

`build/index.html`

However, if I try that, I get:

```
The IndexDocument Suffix is not well formed
```

So I just left the `Index document` and `Error document` to be `index.html`.

But now it can't find the index file:

```
404 Not Found
Code: NoSuchKey
Message: The specified key does not exist.
Key: index.html
```

I tried the suggestions from [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=420827), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44382709/aws-s3-404-not-found) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43005475/s3-cloudfront-app-code-nosuchkey-on-refreshing) but the error persists.

This seems to be a very common issue. So how did you do such that S3 manages to see your `index.html` when it's in a folder?

Answer (score 3):

The Index Document `index.html` is used on a per-folder basis.

So when you request `http://mywebsite.com.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/` it is going to render `/index.html`.

If you request `http://mywebsite.com.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/build/`, it will render `/build/index.html`.

So each folder needs it's own `index.html` file if you want to have that behaviour. You cannot have a single `build/index.html` that is used for all folders.

**Additional note about the Error Document**

The error document is always rendered relative to the root.

So if you requested `/some/folder/that/does/not/exist/`, it will render `/404.html` if `404.html` was configured as your Error Document.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**
After some extensive testing. I figured that the earlier rule does not work for "/" (root) path and creates a continuous redirect then I came up with this rule which works for me.

> ```
> <RoutingRules> 
> <RoutingRule>
> <Condition>
>     <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
> </Condition>
> <Redirect>
>     <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>build/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
> </Redirect> </RoutingRule> </RoutingRules>
> ```

---

You need a custom redirection rule to redirect the /index.html to /build/index.html

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
   <Condition>
     <KeyPrefixEquals> 
       index.html
     </KeyPrefixEquals>
    </Condition>
  <Redirect>
     <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>build/index.html</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith></Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html#advanced-conditional-redirects