# S3 bucket cannot find index.html, gives me a 404 error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, hosting, amazon-route53

I've really tried everything. I've looked at this

- [Can not access index.html from S3 bucket when it's in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48842464/can-not-access-index-html-from-s3-bucket-when-its-in-a-folder?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I've looked at the other references and all over the web. I can't get my index.html to be found by the s3 bucket. I keep getting the error

```
Code: NoSuchKey
Message: The specified key does not exist.
Key: index.html
RequestId: CM1NRYKF55E1R6WJ
HostId: lJtu4pRC/iIXhAxmwrGTDBX+E8zky0G93mZV+kaB+9/j8U51CrVDIc5sjfqmoHF+KGkmEGI/JeI=
```

My buckets are named correctly and the index.html file is literally just "index.html". I don't have an error.html if that means anything? The website does work when I take the object URL

- https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/simonhutch.co.uk/PERSONAL-WEBSITE/index.html

Do I need to put the CSS and JS into a separate folder and connect the html to them? I've tried deleting and re-doing the buckets so many times now it's a joke.

I hope somebody can help me, this is starting to take the michael.

Thank you, if I haven't provided enough information I am happy to provide it :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are putting `index.html` under `PERSONAL-WEBSITE` "folder", you can visit your website at http://simonhutch.co.uk.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/PERSONAL-WEBSITE/

Comment: I appreciate the comment, thank you. Just checked and you're right :)

That being said, is there anyway to just get "www.simonhutch.co.uk" to work?

Comment: Yep, please follow this guide. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/?nc1=h_ls

Comment: Does it make any difference that I have already bought the domain? But thank you! I'll look through that now. I hope it works man :(